# How can I open terminal and run command automatically?

Tags: shell, command-line, terminal

I'm in the terminal emulator. I want to open another terminal to run a specified command.

```
gnome-terminal -e "zsh -c 'pwd; zsh;'"
```

That runs `pwd` and `zsh` consecutively and successfully in another terminal. After `pwd` terminates, zsh launches and I can run other commands in that second  terminal instance.

However, when a different app is launched instead of `pwd`, I can't end that long-running program properly.

For example when I type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> to exit from node.js server in below command, it also closes the terminal. It seems that `SIGINT` is passed to first `zsh` with `-c` option.

```
gnome-terminal -e "zsh -c 'node server.js; zsh;'"
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: If I use zsh as in your code, I reproduce your problem, but bash does not have that problem; if you replace zsh with bash, it works fine for me. Would using bash be acceptable?

Comment: You can also use `gnome-terminal -e "bash -c \"node server.js; zsh\""` so that you still have your favorite shell.

Comment: @Zorgoth Thank you. It works with bash but some commands that spawns another process(maybe by forking?) still exit when sigint is passed.

Comment: Script in answer of @HarshaD works in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this in bash

Apologies in advanced if it does not work.

I wrote a bash script named userInput.sh - this waits for user input and ends.

`

```
## trap ctrl-c and call ctrl_c()

trap ctrl_c INT

function ctrl_c() {

echo "** Trapped CTRL-C"

exit
}

read -p "Press any key to continue... " -n1 -s
```

Now, when I run and press clt+c

```
gnome-terminal -e "bash -c './userInput.sh; bash;'"
```

userInput.sh exits and I still have the bash prompt.

Now I think in your case instead of waiting for user input, you are running node server.js like

```
## trap ctrl-c and call ctrl_c()

trap ctrl_c INT

function ctrl_c() {

echo "** Trapped CTRL-C"

exit
}

node server.js
```

Let's assume that you named the script 'runNodeJs.sh', then command would be

```
gnome-terminal -e "bash -c './runNodeJs.sh; bash;'"
```